# Userdefaults value not persisting despite being synchronized?

Tags: swift, nsuserdefaults

I am utilizing UserDefaults to save a small value that occasionally needs to be written to. I believe I have it set up correctly, but I am not sure why it is not working after I quit the simulator and start it back up again.
The set up:

```
let defaults = UserDefaults.standard
```

It is then written to/modified as follows:

```
defaults.set(true, forKey: "defaultsChecker")
defaults.synchronize()
```

Using a print statement I can see that the value is indeed updated from being nil to being true. However, checking the value in a `viewDidLoad` at the onset of turning the simulator on again (after being quit) as follows:

```
print("The value is is \((defaults.value(forKey: "defaultsChecker") as! Bool)))")
```

This always returns nil at the onset, meaning that it must not be saved/persist through the closing and reopening of the simulator. Not sure why this is the case.

Comment: are you sure no where in the code you are resetting value for key "defaultsChecker" ?

Comment: Assuming that you have checked the spelling of the key ("defaultsChecker"), you should search for "defaultsChecker" in the whole project to make sure that it is not set to `false` anywhere. Btw, I'd suggest to  declare a constant with the value of "defaultsChecker" and use it as a key to avoid the mistake of typing it wrong when you need to use it...

Comment: Do not use `value(forKey:)` to read a value from `UserDefaults` unless you have a clearly understood need to use key-value coding. You set a `Bool` so read a `Bool` using `bool(forKey:)`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

don't use `value(forKey:)` for read Bool Value from `UserDefaults`
you when you set bool then use `bool(forKey:)`

```
let defaults = UserDefaults.standard
defaults.set(true, forKey: "defaultsChecker")
print("The value is is \(defaults.bool(forKey: "defaultsChecker"))")
```

here shown multiple types of value in `UserDefaults`

[image]

and you want to get values,Then try this

```
defaults.integer(forKey: )
defaults.string(forKey: )
defaults.double(forKey: )
defaults.array(forKey: )
defaults.dictionary(forKey: )
defaults.data(forKey: )
defaults.bool(forKey:)
```

and there is no need to use `synchronize()` they automatically sync .

in your question you try this...

```
if let defaultsChecker =  UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "defaultsChecker") as? Bool {
        if defaultsChecker {
            debugPrint(defaultsChecker)// value has True
        } else  {
            debugPrint(false)// value has False
        }
    }
```

Comment: I can switch it to `.bool(forKey: )` but the issue is I need to first check if it was written to at all yet, so I need to check with an if statement: `if defaults.value(forKey: "defaultsChecker") != nil{}` but I can't check if its not equal to nil if I use `.bool` instead of `.value`. How do I get around this?

Comment: @AlekPiasecki Check i'm Update my Answer